# Adding a footer to listView only if listView is non empty

Tags: android

I am using a custom listView and trying to add a footer.  However the footer appers even if there is no data. The code I am using is as follows:

```
       View footer = View.inflate(this, R.layout.footer_xml, null);
       listView.addFooterView(footer);
```

Is there any way to display the footer only when the list is non empty? Also if I add a footer in the above way, it seems to be a part of the list view in the OnItemClickListener. I dont want this to happen since I want some action to be initiated only if the user exactly clicks on the footer image.
I know that I can use

```
ImageView b = (ImageView)footer.findViewById(R.id.my_list_button);
b.setOnClickListener(this);
```

but only if no action is triggered in the onItemClickListner of the listView.

Comment: just check the number of items in the listview when you are adding it to the list and if they are non-zero you need to add the footer view as you used the code and if not dont do that

Comment: Whatever I do the added footer is always a part of the OnItemClickListener. Is there any way to prevent that from happening

Comment: Instead of adding it as a footer my way of dealing this issue is to create the layout at the bottom of the listview in the same xml.
whenever i need the footer i would make the layout visible and when its not required i would make it invisible

Comment: You mean to say make the image disappear using .setVisibilty() right?